# Problem in C++ class with static variables and functions

Tags: c++, class, ubuntu, static, g++

Can someone tell me what is problem in the following class, g++ is giving errors on ubuntu:

```
class FibonacciGenerator
{
    private:
        static int num1, num2, counting;

    public:

        static void Reset()
        {
            num1 = 0; num2 = 1;
            counting = 1;
        }

        static int GetCount()
        {
            return counting;
        }

        static int GetNext()
        {
            int val = 0;
            if(counting == 1) val = num1;
            else if(counting == 2) val = num2;
            else 
            {
                val = num1 + num2;
                num1 = num2;
                num2 = val;
            }
            counting ++;

            return val;
        }
};
```

Comment: What errors are there? Please provide more detail with your question, the question in its current form can not be reliably answered.

Comment: guess in the dark - you've declared your variables static, but forgot to define them somewhere?

Comment: one more thing, why `static` anyway?

Comment: I wanted to make the class very easy to use without making any instances etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `static int num1, num2, counting;` in a class definition does not define those variables, it only declares them. If they are used they must also be defined.

A complete example of this is as follows:

```
//Begin FibonacciGenerator.hpp
#ifndef FIBONACCI_GENERATOR_HPP
#define FIBONACCI_GENERATOR_HPP
class FibonacciGenerator
{
private:
    static int num1, num2, counting;

public:
/* as above */
};
#endif //FIBONACCI_GENERATOR_HPP
//End FibonacciGenerator.hpp

//Begin FibonacciGenerator.cpp
#include "FibonacciGenerator.h"
int FibonacciGenerator::num1;
int FibonacciGenerator::num2;
int FibonacciGenerator::counting;
//End FibonacciGenerator.cpp
```

If FibonacciGenerator is declared in a namespace, then these static member definitions must also be in that namespace.

Using static members like this is probably a very bad idea. It would be better to make them instance variables, so that you could have multiple independent `FibonacciGenerators` in separate parts of the code.

Comment: i have declared the variables in Reset function. Besides, i am using the class currently in only one place and its for some testings etc, and so only static so i thought i would make it much simpler by not going into class instances.

Comment: In the `Reset` function you assigned to the variables. This is different from defining them.

Comment: One reason to make them instance variables would be that this problem would go away. You could then have an entirely header-only implementation, and you would not get the undefined reference errors.

Comment: I can't define outside the class since the static variables are private. Is it some limitation of C++?

Comment: No, this is not a limitation of C++. You must be doing something wrong. I will update my answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 2):

You have only declared the static members. You should also define them in a cpp file like this

```
int FibonacciGenerator::num1 /*= 0*/;
int FibonacciGenerator::num2 /*= 1*/;
int FibonacciGenerator::counting /*= 0*/;
```

when you write

```
static T v; //if static were removed, this would also be a definition
```

inside a class, it is only a declaration, but every program must contain exactly one definition of every variable that is used (as per the One-Definition-Rule). hth

Comment: where should i define them? the file in which the class is defined or where the class-functions are called?

Comment: @inam101: Normally, you should have a .h file where the class definition is, and a cpp file where the member function definitons are. In this case the static member definitions should go in the cpp file. If you dump them all in one file, then the definitions should be anywhere after the class